How can I know if the context is being set correctly in pysnmp?
I'm trying to make an snmp server with custom handlers. Looking online, I found that the following code is supposed to do this:
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdrsp, context
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.smi import instrum
from pysnmp.proto.api import v2c

# -- Configurable items --
srvHost = '127.0.0.1'
srvPort = 1610
snmpCommunity = 'public'
snmpArea = 'public'
baseMquestOid = (1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 31971)
baseCommonOid = (1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1)
basePath = '/usr/share/snmp/mibs'
asn1Path = "http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/"

# Create an SNMP context
snmpContext = context.SnmpContext(snmpEngine)


# Very basic Management Instrumentation Controller without
# any Managed Objects attached. It supports only GET's and
# always echos request var-binds in response.
class EchoMibInstrumController(instrum.AbstractMibInstrumController):

    def readMibObjects(self, *varBinds, **context):
        cbFun = context.get('cbFun')
        if cbFun:
            cbFun([(ov[0], "Example") for ov in varBinds], **context) 


# Create a custom Management Instrumentation Controller and register at
# SNMP Context under ContextName 'my-context'
snmpContext.registerContextName(
    v2c.OctetString('mq -context'),  # Context Name
    EchoMibInstrumController()  # Management Instrumentation
)

# Register GET&SET Applications at the SNMP engine for a custom SNMP context
cmdrsp.GetCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
cmdrsp.SetCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)

# Register an imaginary never-ending job to keep I/O dispatcher running forever
snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)

# Run I/O dispatcher which would receive queries and send responses
try:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()

finally:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()

Which should create a context that uses that custom readMibObjects function. So if I call a specific existing OID with a get request snmpget -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1:1610 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.1 , let's say that OID belongs to 'SNMPv2-MIB' in the server; I should get something like the following format:
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = Example
But I am getting the following:
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = PYSNMP-MIB::pysnmp
So I think that the server is not using the context I'm passing it. Do I need to write something to make the server used the registered context? How can I make it use the custom function I'm passing it to handle the get requests?
I tried debugging by printing the context names with print(snmpContext.contextNames) while initializing the server. That returns the following: {b'': <pysnmp.smi.instrum.MibInstrumController object at 0x78d381975820>, b'mq-context': <__main__.CustomMibInstrumController object at 0x78d381777400>}. I can see that a b'' context exists. Maybe it's using that one. So I tried unregistering using snmpContext.unregisterContextName(OctetString('')), which managed to leave only mq-context in the contextNames variable expecting for the server to use my own context. But when I do that the server doesn't return anything in the snmp get request (or any request).

there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

what is context , snmpEngine,  instrum, v2c and cmdrsp ?  there are too many undefined variables to understand what is going on....

I edited the post to make a minimal reproductible example

Using readMibObjects is a red flag indicating that you were reading the wrong documentation that points to the never released 5.x code by Ilya. As new maintainers of PYSNMP, we don't support that at all. Please visit https://pysnmp.com to learn what's supported.

I was using an old version of pysnmp. It turns out that it was maintained by a new organization and my code (based on code I found online and legacy) was deprecated.

It would be helpful for others, if you can mention the version that worked for you.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
